# Arrays and Caching

Tags: c++

If I have a `char` array that is of length 8 billion. Would breaking it into smaller arrays increase performance by improving caching? Basically, I will iterate the array and do some comparisons. If not, what is the most optimal way of using an array with such length.

I am reading a file in binary form into an array, and will be performing binary comparisons on different parts of the file.

Comment: Can you add more detail of what you're trying to do, and where the data comes from? Is it being generated, read from disk? What _exactly_ is the processing you're doing on the data?

Comment: @Anonymous I just edited the question

Comment: Never ever use the term "billion". Do you mean 10^9 or 10^12? If you do just a 1-D sequential read, breaking it up into smaller pieces usually does not improve caching. If you speak of caches, very important is the used hardware architecture. But here is also the often given advice valid: If you are not an expert on this field (and it seems so) let the compiler do it for you.

Comment: What comparisons exactly? How do you decide which parts of the data to compare? Without information, it's impossible to answer the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 GB worth of data will inevitably ruin data locality so one way or the other you either have to manage your memory in smaller pieces or your OS will do the disk swapping of virtual memory.

There is, however, an alternative - a so-called `mmap`. Essentially this allows you to map a file into a virtual memory space and your OS then takes the task of accessing it and loading the necessary pages into RAM, while your access to this file becomes nothing more than just a simple memory addressing.

Read more about `mmap` at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do this once then just run through it. The programming effort may not be worth the time gained.

I am assuming you want to  do this again and again which is why you want to optimize it. It would surely help to know if your iteration and comparisons need to be done sequentially etc? Without some problem domain input it is kind of difficult to give a generic optimization here.

If it can be done in parallel and you have to do it multiple times I suggest you take a look at MapReduce techniques to solve this.